# Reissner-Nordström Black Holes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, symmetry, reissner-nordstrom-metric

The Reissner-Nordström black holes are described by the metric,

\begin{align}
ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}+\frac{Q^2}{r^2}\right)dt^2 + \frac{1}{1-\frac{2M}{r}+\frac{Q^2}{r^2}}+r^2d\Omega^2
\end{align}
where $M$ is the mass of the black-hole and $Q$ is the charge of the black hole. I am using the convention of $(-,+,+,+)$ here. The minimum mass horizon, which one can calculate, is given by $M_{min} = Q^2$. Part of the derivation is at: http://aesop.phys.utk.edu/ads-cft/L3.pdf. (Notes on AdS/CFT Correspondence from University of Tennessee, notes 3).

Suppose we approach the horizon, the metric begins to approach the $AdS_2 \times S^2$ metric, given by,
\begin{align}
ds^2 = R_1^2\frac{-dt^2}{z^2}+R_1^2 \frac{dz^2}{z^2} +R_2^2 z^2 d\Omega^2.
\end{align}
Note that in the link I provided, there is a sign switch (since the note writes for a Euclidean AdS).

I was wondering, what would be the overall generators of the group? Is it just the generators of $AdS_2$ and the generators of $S^2$ (which are from $SO(3)$)? Are there not some more complicated generators that mix the two spaces?

Comment: The isometries are $SO(2,1)\times SO(3)$. I don't think there are any that mix the two.